# Back button in a console text game (c++)

Tags: c++

Text based game in which there are multiple menus to access, and I would like to add a back button option or choice to it. They are all in a switch statement, for example:

```
cout<<"1. Open menu 1<<endl<< 2. Open menu 2"<<endl;
int choice;
cin>>choice;
switch(choice){
case 1:
 //Opens menu 1 and shows more text for example:
cout<<"1. Open submenu 1<<endl<< 2. Open submenu 2"<<endl;
int choice2;
cin>>choice2;
switch(choice2){
  //Opens ANOTHER menu and so on and so forth
}
break;

case 2:
 //Opens menu 2 and shows different text
cout<<"1. Open submenu 1<<endl<< 2. Open submenu 2"<<endl;
int choice2;
cin>>choice2;
switch(choice2){
//Opens ANOTHER menu and so on and so forth
}
break;
}
```

How, in this switch statement do I make a sort of back button if the user went into a menu accidentally?
Thank you.

Comment: "button" in a text console app? Do you mean just another option for the menu?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes.

Comment: your question misses too many details. In the code you posted there are no multiple menus but only one, hence its not clear what a "back" should do in that code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: assuming `case 1:` is just calling some `menu1();` you just need to `return` from `menu1` to get "back"

Comment: Can't you simply add it to your menu, just like to option for menus 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
main_menu:
cout << "1. Open menu 1" << endl 
     << "2. Open menu 2" << endl;
int choice;
cin >> choice;
switch (choice) {
case 1:
    //Opens menu 1 and shows more text
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        goto main_menu;
    }
    break;

case 2:
    //Opens menu 2 and shows different text
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        goto main_menu;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: But how do you set a "main menu"? Is there a tag? because writing just main_menu makes an error :(

Comment: add the ':' after main_menu